# ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "," in psycopg2 update query using extras.execute_values

Tags: python, postgresql, sql-update, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am trying to update a Redshift table using psycopg2.extras.execute_values module. Below is the code

```
from psycopg2 import extras
cur = con.cursor()

update_query = """update my_table
                  set gender = data.gender 
                  from (VALUES %s) as data (gender,firstname) 
                  where my_table.firstname = data.firstname
                  and my_table.gender is NULL"""

new_values = [("F","Charlene"),("F","BRITTANY")]

extras.execute_values (cur, update_query, new_values)
```

However I am getting below error:

[image]

Tried various combinations of quotes, double quotes and brackets but no luck.

TIA.

- Rohan

Comment: try first with `new_values  = ("F","Charlene")`

Comment: Getting "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" Error with new_values = ("F","Charlene")

Comment: @prashantrana Also ttried `new_values = [("F","Charlene")]` and error was ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 3:                   from (VALUES ('F','Charlene') **)** as data (pr...

Comment: This works perfectly both in Postgres 9.5 and 11. Check whether the syntax is correct in Redshift.

Comment: @klin the version I am using is ('PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.5463',)

Comment: @klin is there any way I can perform this update in the version that I have?

Comment: Redshift differs from modern Postgres in many aspects, unfortunately, I have no access to Redshift to check this.

Comment: @klin Thank you for this help. I have to use executemany function for this update query I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to reply, but here is the answer I got.

cursor.executemany().

I tried to do a lot of searches but never got the solution myself.  I am using python.

More details in the below URL.

1. https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/830
2. https://zetcode.com/python/psycopg2/  (detailed use case of cursor.executemany())